# How to use the VLC.DotNet.Core API on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, vlc

I've made a C# console application which compiles with mono (`mcs`) and I can run that on both Windows and Raspberry Pi (raspbian).  The application uses the NuGet package `Vlc.DotNet.Core` to interface with the VLC installation that exists on my Windows machine, and this works.

I know the path to `libvlc.dll` (which the api requires in order to work) on my Windows machine, the problem is that I can't find that on the Raspberry Pi even after installing VLC on there with `apt-get install vlc`.

I've searched the Pi for the location of vlc, and entered that path into the constructor of `VlcMediaPlayer` as follows;

```cs
new VlcMediaPlayer(new DirectoryInfo("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc"));
```

I have very little confidence that I've used the correct path...  Clearly there are major differences between VLC's Windows installation and the one for Raspbian.

The resulting exception on the Pi reads:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
  at Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcLibraryLoader..ctor (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dynamicLinkLibrariesPath) [0x0007a] in <baf298be89ec4e8f88b59dde806086ea>:0 
  at Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcLibraryLoader.GetOrCreateLoader (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dynamicLinkLibrariesPath) [0x00051] in <baf298be89ec4e8f88b59dde806086ea>:0 
  at Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcManager..ctor (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dynamicLinkLibrariesPath, System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <baf298be89ec4e8f88b59dde806086ea>:0 
  at Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer..ctor (System.IO.DirectoryInfo vlcLibDirectory) [0x00000] in <9af967e78de14038abf8c3386a2b8049>:0 
  at MonoApp.Classes.VLCFactory.Create () [0x0000b] in <0b03f50fed2542db8a444bf356ef64b6>:0 
  at MonoApp.Classes.VLCCommands.VLCCommand_Play.Execute (Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer& mediaPlayer, System.String[] args) [0x00007] in <0b03f50fed2542db8a444bf356ef64b6>:0 
  at MonoApp.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00019] in <0b03f50fed2542db8a444bf356ef64b6>:0
```

**EDIT:**

I've found the source files to the VlcLibraryLoader class (as seen in the exception) [here](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/develop/src/Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops/VlcLibraryLoader.cs), and apparently it's looking for three dlls, only two of which exist on Windows so I'm guessing that the linked source files are slightly outdated.  The point here is that they're looking for `.dll` files, not the `.so` files that exist on the Raspberry Pi, so I'm not surprised it's failing.  The question remains, however...

**QUESTION:**

- Am I using the correct vlc package `libvlc-dev`, are there any other dependencies I need?
- Is `Vlc.DotNet.Core` API known to work on `Raspbian` with `mono` or am I on a hopeless path?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Vlc.DotNet.Core can be made to work on raspbian with mono. It is initially targetted to work on Windows, as you know.

LibVLCSharp probably will work on raspbian though, since it works with ubuntu.

LibVLC/GTK linux install guide: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/blob/master/docs/linux-setup.md

LibVLCSharp.GTK sample: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/tree/master/Samples/LibVLCSharp.GTK.Sample

Good luck.

Comment: I'd not heard of LibVLCSharp, that's looking very promising!  I'll try it out!

Comment: Does Libvlcsharp work with winforms, C# and raspbian?

Comment: libvlcsharp works with winforms, c# and raspbian, separetely. WinForms on linux is dead and should not be used.